# Laravel : get the top 10 users from answer's survey table

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to display the top 10 users who are answering for the surveys

I tried this

```
public function topuser()
{
    $bestuser = Answer::whereRaw('id = (select max(count(`id`)) from Answer)')->get();

    return view('dashboard.top')->with('bestuser', $bestuser);
}
```

But it gives me an error.

**Answer model:**

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['answer'];
    protected $table = 'answer';

    public function survey() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
    }

    public function question() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
}
```

Answer Migrate file :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('Answer', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('question_id');
        $table->integer('survey_id');
        $table->string('answer');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

How to fix that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for top users (those with the most posts), it would probably be easier to come from the **User** model angle.  Thus, pull a count from the **Answer** relationship on the **User** model, something like this:

```
$bestuser = User::withCount('answers as answer_count')
                 ->orderBy('answer_count', 'desc')
                 ->take(10)
                 ->get();
```

Or if you just want a simple list:

```
$bestuser = User::withCount('answers as answer_count')
                 ->orderBy('answer_count', 'desc')
                 ->take(10)
                 ->pluck('answer_count', 'name');
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::answer as answer_count() it;s not working :(

Comment: Did you put this line under namespace?
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Comment: yes i think could u check please namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\Answer;
use App\Survey;
use DB;

Comment: Does your **User** model actually have the `answers` relationship correctly defined?  If not, this will cause an error.  But to get what you want, you need that relationship, then it is as simple as using the code above.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
public function topuser()
{
    $bestuser = Answer::OrderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();

    return view('dashboard.top')->with('bestuser', $bestuser);
}
```

Comment: i got all list , i want to get the most or higher users answered or order by desc the count user_id